# columna con total de ventas día actual y otra columna con el total de las ventas del día anterior SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito realizar un query que me traiga el total de las compras de cada día y en una columna nueva traiga el total de las compras pero del día anterior. como hago para pedirle las compras del día anterior?

Tengo una tabla con dos columnas, "Fecha" y "Compras". Necesito crear un query para tener una tabla con la fecha, otra columa con las ventas totales de ese dia y otra columna con las ventas totales del dia anterior

El motor de bsusqueda es MySQL

```
select Fecha, sum(Compra_del_dia) as Compras_del_dia, sum(Compra_del_dia) as Compras_del_dia_anterior 

 from invoice

 where total2 = (select DATE_ADD(Fecha, interval -1 DAY))

group by Fecha;
```

Tabla original

| Fecha | Compras_del_dia |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2019 | 5 |
| 1/1/2019 | 5 |
| 2/1/2019 | 4 |
| 2/1/2019 | 16 |
| 2/1/2019 | 5 |
| 3/1/2019 | 30 |

Necesito realizar un query para llegar a esto,

| Fecha | Compras_del_dia | Compras_del_dia_anterior |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2019 | 10 | 0 |
| 2/1/2019 | 25 | 10 |
| 3/1/2019 | 30 | 25 |

Comment: que as intentado hasta ahora? que as investigado? podrias colocar tu query? y las tablas implicadas?

Comment: @Jorge, que version de MySQL utilizas? ¿Que debería suceder si una fecha no existe? Ejemplo, agregamos el registro `5/1/2019 | 40`, falta la fecha `4/1/2019` no existe

Answer (score 0):

Podría ser algo así:

```
set @i:=0;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE compras_diarias
SELECT @i:=@i+1 id,c1.*
  FROM (
    SELECT Fecha,
      SUM(Compras_del_dia) dia_actual
      FROM invoice
      GROUP BY 1
  ) c1;
SELECT c1.*,c2.dia_actual dia_anterior
  FROM compras_diarias c1
  LEFT JOIN compras_diarias c2
  ON c1.id=c2.id+1
  ORDER BY c1.Fecha;
```

Para tu dataset de muestra:

```
CREATE TABLE invoice(
  Fecha date,
  Compras_del_dia int
  );
INSERT INTO invoice (Fecha, Compras_del_dia) VALUES
  ('2019-01-01',5),
  ('2019-01-01',5),
  ('2019-01-02',4),
  ('2019-01-02',16),
  ('2019-01-02',5),
  ('2019-01-03',30);
```

Obtendrías:

```
+------+------------+------------+--------------+
| id   | Fecha      | dia_actual | dia_anterior |
+------+------------+------------+--------------+
|    1 | 2019-01-01 |         10 |         NULL |
|    2 | 2019-01-02 |         25 |           10 |
|    3 | 2019-01-03 |         30 |           25 |
+------+------------+------------+--------------+
```

Espero que sea lo que buscabas. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios para aclarar aquellos puntos que puedan resultar más difíciles de entender.